# How to download the file with original extension from Firebase storage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to download files from Firebase storage. But when I download it, it's giving some files with `.bin` extension. But I want to get the original file name.

Here is my code.

```
try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                    8192);
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                    +"/Download/"+ URLUtil.guessFileName(f_url[0], null, null));
            Log.i("File name",URLUtil.guessFileName(f_url[0], null, null));
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
```

In there `f_url` is the firebase download url. Thank you.

Comment: Why aren't you using the Firebase SDK? Here's the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files

Comment: I tried. First I created File localFile = File.createTempFile("ayefile","",getExternalFilesDir(null)); then added that file to firebase local download function. But i'm still not getting the extension. :(

Answer (score 3):

The built in way of doing this is actually quite straightforward:

```
StorageReference reference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...");

// Assuming that the file is "name.extension" in Storage
String name = reference.getName().split(".")[0]
String extension = reference.getName().split(".")[1]

File localFile = File.createTempFile(name, extension);

reference.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        // Local temp file has been created
    }
});
```

But if you don't want to do it the easy way...

Let's take a brief look at how you're naming your file: `URLUtil.guessFileName(f_url[0], null, null)`

According to the `URLUtil.guessFileName()` docs: "Guesses canonical filename that a download would have, using the URL and contentDisposition. File extension, if not defined, is added based on the mimetype."

I'm assuming that your `f_url[0]` is a file with no extension, and since you provide no `contentDisposition` or `mimetype` as arguments to `guessFileName`, there's no way it can possibly know what file extension you want.

You can get the `contentDisposition` and `contentType` (same as `mimetype`) from [Storage Metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/file-metadata), and if you name your file in Storage with an extension, you should be good to go.

Comment: Just for clarification, what if the file isn't uploaded with an extension? is there a way to get the extension base on mime type before the local tempFile is created?

Comment: @AndrewLam you could fetch the metadata, get the content type, maintain a lookup table (or potentially use a built in MIME type to extension mapping), and then download the file and create an appropriate extension.